# React onClick not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use the onClick method in React to log a simple word out when a button is clicked

```
<button> onClick={console.log('hello world!')}> Submit < / button >
```

'hello world!' is only logged out when the page initially loads when i click the button it doesn't log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React expects `onclick` handler to be a function but `console.log('hello world!')` will only show the message and return `undefined`. Please try this:

```
<button onClick={() => console.log('hello world!')}>Submit</button>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/6k9w5eem/

Answer (score 0):

onClick accepts a function. You are assigning the return of console.log() execution. What you need to do is something like

```
<button onClick={() => console.log('hello world!')}>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Ohhh ! I'm 1 minute late:D